# Makefile c++11 support

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, makefile

i recently started a small project in C++. I created a simply Makefile:

```
    CC=g++
    CFLAGS =-std=c++0x -I. -c
    VPATH = src include



    vpath %.c src

    vpath %.h include

    TabooSearch : main.o Task.o TabooList.o
                  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o TabooSearch main.o Task.o TabooList.o
```

The problem is that when i run `make` i get this kind of errors form gcc:
 
`error:  ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope` 
I don't have any ides what is wrong with my Makefile, can someone help me solve this problem. My gcc version is 4.7.2 on Debian
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think the Makefile is responsible for C++ errors?

Comment: using namespace std? or std::nullptr? in your source file...

Comment: "Makefile c++11 support" ... "-std=c++0x" ...

Comment: What happens if you run `g++ -std=c++0x -I. -c -o TabooSearch src/main.c src/Task.c src/TabooList.c`?

Comment: Grmpf. That problem requires you to unveil the (c++) file which creates that error-message

Comment: `vpath %.c src`? Shouldn't this be `.cpp` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using implicit rules for building the `.o` files, you should use `CXXFLAGS` to set the C++ flags:

> CXXFLAGS =-std=c++0x

No need for `-I.` or `-c`.

I would add a few more flags to get decent errors and warnings:

> CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std+c++0x

Likewise for `g++`. If your default settings do not invoke g++, then you need to add

> CXX = g++

Comment: Also should be using CXX instead of CC

Comment: Tanks that helped(you just have a small error ther you problably mean to write `CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++0x`)! I don't understand why i but i will read make documentation. Thanks a lot.