# How do I enable GCC compiler C++11 flag by default on Windows?

Tags: windows, c++11, command-line, g++

I want to avoid typing "-std=c++11" on the command line every time.
Is there any simple/direct solution to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, upgrade to GCC 6.

> The default mode for C++ is now -std=gnu++14 instead of -std=gnu++98.

You can get a GCC supporting new GCC for example here:

https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: How do I do that for Windows? If possible, can you share a link?

Comment: GCC 6 is available in the [Nuwen distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html), which contains some libraries in the package as well (most notably Boost). Unfortunately, at the time of writing, this is the only GCC 6 there is for Windows...

Comment: @rubenvb So, there's no GNU version of it? When do you think it'll come out?

Comment: I don't think there are "official" binary distributions of GCC on Windows. MinGW is the closest.

Comment: @BriefcaseJoe: The GNU version is [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/) (the source tarballs available from ftp.gnu.org). There is not, and never has been, a "GNU" binary distribution. Even for Linux, that is up to the various distros.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine There are no "official" binary distribution of GCC anywhere.

Comment: @BriefcaseJoe That is a very good build, just use it and if something seems wrong with it, ask on e.g. mingw-w64-public@sourceforge.net or on the mingw-w64 forums (I lurk there and will probably be able to help).

Answer (score 0):

Windows has the [`DOSKEY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx) command to define macros (which are analogous to Unix aliases).

Something like this should work:

```
doskey g++="g++ --std=c++11 $*"
```

A [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) and the `CXXFLAGS` variable is an alternative (e.g. see [Makefile c++11 support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13828195/3235496)).