# Makefile to support c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile

I recently started a small project in C++. I created a simply Makefile:

```
output: main.o google_api.o
    g++ main.o google_api.o -o output
    rm *.o
    clear
    ./output

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

test.o: google_api.cpp google_api.h
    g++ -c google_api.cpp
```

And when I compile my code I get the next error -

> non-aggregate type 'vector' cannot be initialized
>         with an initializer list

I am check for this issue and find that I need to add -std=c++11 support to my makefile to fix the problem. I add this command to the code:

> g++ -std=c++11 main.o google_api.o -o output

But this is not make any change. I would love if someone can help me to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: The line you changed is the line for *linking*, not for *compiling*. You need to add the flag to both.

Comment: I also suggest you learn more about `make` and makefiles. Especially about *variables*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change this:

```
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

to:

```
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
```

You may as well use something like this as basis for your [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -MMD -std=c++11
LDLIBS=-lm # list libs here
output: main.o google_api.o
clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.d output
-include $(wildcard *.d)
```

There are also similar questions on stackoverflow: [Makefile c++11 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828195/makefile-c11-support?rq=1)

Comment: Should it be CXX rather than CC?